# Android Load Feed Data along with multiple images to SQLite

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, android-handler, imagedownload

Need to download feed from URL and save the feed item data into sqlite.
Some of the feed items may contain images. The images need to be downloaded and saved to device.(A reference will be saved in sqlite). All this happens in the background. No interaction with UI/Main thread is necessary.

I coded the part of downloading the feed data(JSON), parsing JSON data(Using GSON) and saving them to data base in single 'AsyncTask'.
Can I have the logic of downloading images too in the same AsyncTask? or should I start other Async Tasks to download the images inside the current Async Task?
I read about Handlers, should I use handlers to download the image ?

I am thinking of saving the Image URLs to a object in main Async Task and start another AsyncTask 'onPostExecute' which downloads images sequentially.
Any issues with the this approach?

I am worried what happens if user leaves the app while the above process is running. May be in between of processing the feed.
If I use 'Service' will the process continue to run until it finishes even if user leaves the app?(I read the documentation but did not get this part).
Or should I programmatically keep track of the progress, like items that got processed and not process them next time etc?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to store image in data base then you have to download the image first and then convert it into bitmap and then in byte array.And while getting from data base then same reverse procedure will have to be followed.

```
                         or
```

you can store image as BLOB in your database

```
public static byte[] urlToImageBLOB(String url) throws IOException {
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    entity = null;
    httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }
    return EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
}
```

Now you need to fetch the image

```
public static Bitmap getImageFromBLOB(byte[] mBlob) {
    byte[] bb = mBlob;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);

}
```

To Set the Image

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageFromBLOB(cursor.getBlob(object.getColumnIndex("book_thumb"))));
```

OR

you can also use Handler for the task

```
protected Drawable Imagehandler(String url) {
    try {
        url=url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        InputStream is = (InputStream)this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {   
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println("error at URI"+e);
        return null;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("io exception: "+e);
        System.out.println("Image NOT FOUND");
        return null;
    } 
}

protected Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

this will convert your imageUrl to Drawble at runtime, then set the Drawble to Imageview of Gallery

Comment: Instead of saving the image in database I want to download it to device(cache) and save the reference(filepath and name)in database. Thanks for the code though. Mainly I am looking for help with better usage of Async Tasks.